How can I get my token using Token Extensions Metadata to display in Solana Explorer?
Why doesn't Token Extensions metadata display properly on Solana Explorer while Solscan, Solana.fm & Phantom wallet displays metadata without issues?
For example, on devnet, I've created a test spl-token2022/Token Extension token with metadata extensions enabled, and on Solana Explorer, I see "Unknown Token" listed above the token overview.
If I use spl-token without metadata extensions, and instead go the Metaplex route, the tokens metadata does display above the token overview, but there's an associated warning message. See examples below:
With metadata extensions enabled:

Without metadata extensions enabled (using Metaplex program):

Now, here's where things get interesting. Looking at CoinGecko for other token-extension projects, I see the following:
Exhibit A: https://explorer.solana.com/address/G7rwEgk8KgQ4RUTnMy2W2i7dRDq4hXHD4CSp9PSmSbRW
Exhibit B: https://explorer.solana.com/address/CKfatsPMUf8SkiURsDXs7eK6GWb4Jsd6UDbs7twMCWxo
Exhibit C: https://explorer.solana.com/address/FLUXBmPhT3Fd1EDVFdg46YREqHBeNypn1h4EbnTzWERX
Exhibit D: https://explorer.solana.com/address/7usVzynPTUJ9czdS96ezm9C6Z3hCsjb7j6TMKipURyyQ
Source: https://www.coingecko.com/en/categories/token-2022
Notice that:
1.) The 4 token2022 projects above aren't using any metadata extensions
2.) These 4 projects also aren't using the metaplex program
So, how are those token2022 projects able to get their metadata recognized by Solana Explorer and NOT have "Unknown token" or a "Warning!" message displayed above the token overview? At this point I don't know which route to go.
1.) Use token2022 with metaplex program and have the metadata display correctly, but risk scaring people away because there's a "Warning!" message above the token overview.
2.) Use token2022 with metadata/metadata pointer extensions and have no "Warning!" message above the token overview, but risk scaring people away because there's "Unknown token" displayed above token overview.
Neither seem like good choices, and so I (and probably many others) would prefer the correct way to go about this. I've even tried using metadata extensions with metaplex, but the metaplex program looks to be incompatible with metadata extensions. I'm really hoping someone can point me in the right direction on this.
Thanks!

Ken I posted a similar question days ago ( below ) & my question was CLOSED by a moderator. No answer to your question can be found in my opinion. I've reached out to roughly 15 folks at solana ( top devs ) on linkedin & twitter and have had no response  ! ((((((( UPDATE the gentlemen a Mr. Jacob Creech did respond to my query on twitter. I asked him to weigh in on this question. ))))))) The tokens you mention are not using the 2 metadata extensions as you point out & are using metaplex i believe. But due to some kinks in token 2022 the metadata displays & doesn't READ as metaplex ( a guess

I think I may have stumbled across a workaround yesterday. If we look at https://fluxbeam.xyz/app/tokens, we see a list of Token2022 projects. If we click on the token's address, we're taken to Solana.fm. From what I see, the common denominator is that token22 spl-token's that are "Jupiter Verified" have their metadata showing correctly on Solana Explorer. See this project: https://solana.fm/address/mmonechkLNdUxDbvP9Yntwo459QfUmqDdzV95DNvnr6?cluster=mainnet-alpha Notice that "Mutant" has metadata ext. & also has its metadata showing correctly on SE. I'm going to test this route & report back.

Update: as of August 29 2024, names and metadata and images are now shown for Token Extensions tokens - thanks Noah!
Here's your token:

Regarding mixing token extensions and metaplex - you don't need metaplex for Token Extensions tokens. Instead, you:

use Token Metadata extension to write the metadata directly to the token mint
use Metadata Pointer to point the mint to itself to find the metadata.

This guide shows you how to make a token with included metadata.
The other answerer is right in that Solana Foundation and Labs generally don't encourage making tokens that use both Token Extensions and Metaplex at the same time - eg why make a token using permanent delegate extension and metaplex for metadata, when both of these features (permanent delegate and metadata) are already built into the Token Extensions program?
See Why does Solana Explorer show "Token names and logos are not unique" for my token? to understand the...

Warning! Token names and logos are not unique

...message and learn how to how to become a well-known token.

Hi Mike. Thanks for the comment. I'm not sure if you've read my response to "YesOurAppsTALK," but I've stumbled across something interesting the last day or so. While observing V2 tokens on https://fluxbeam.xyz/app/tokens, I see that any token that is "Jupiter Verified" has its metadata displaying correctly on SE e.g. https://explorer.solana.com/address/mmonechkLNdUxDbvP9Yntwo459QfUmqDdzV95DNvnr6 Notice that this token is Jupiter Verified on Solana.fm. So would it be safe to assume that the temporary workaround solution is to get our projects verified on Jupiter? Interested on your thoughts..

@KenP Yes, I've updated my answer with some info on what solana.fm and explorer use for 'well known' tokens.

thanks for verifying. Your updated answer is sufficient enough for me to mark as the accepted answer. Thanks, again.
